# ADF Delta Copy Activity fails, delete partly copied file from data lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a hourly  delta load pipeline in that i have a  copy activity to copy data from sql server to datalake parquet format with folder structure (YY/MM/DD/table_nameHH) in For each activity:

after copy activity i have success/failure procedure to update records in control table

[image]

i need to ensure if any copy activity failed in between i need to remove that partly copied file from data lake. how to put that condition to pickand delete that dynamic file in my pipeline.

Thanks in Advance

p.s i am pretty new to this tool and learning daily.

Comment: Hi @Kumar AK, hope you're doing well. If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Thanks Leon for your input. You said if condition should behind the copy activity? then how can we get  @equals(activity('Copy_Dimcustomer_AC').output.executionDetails.status,'Succeeded') if we add copy activity befor copy? do you mean do i need to add after copy? if i add copy after then during the copy if it's fail then our if condition will not work for failure cases right?

Comment: Hi @Kumar AK, that's the output of the copy active, we can get the copy active status from the output JSON string.  According the status value, we could know if the copy active succeeded or failed. I made the example according my understanding of your screenshots. In each inner active, it's a flow actually. If if condition true, run the true active flow, false to false active  flow. You could get more details from the if condition document.

Comment: Please let me know if it's helpful for you, thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ref these steps bellow:

You could add an [If condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) behind the `Copy_DimCustomer_AC` active:
[image]

In If condition expressions, build the expression to judge if `Copy_DimCustomer_AC.executionDetails.status` equals "Succeeded", if ture, then the copy active succeeded:

```
@equals(activity('Copy_Dimcustomer_AC').output.executionDetails.status,'Succeeded')
```

[image]

True actives:

[image]

False active: add a delete active to delete the file and run the `Log_failure_status_AC`:

[image]

HTH.